Comint mode: deleting the output block containing point
I know comint-delete-output can be used to kill the last block of output produced. I'm looking for something that can be used to kill (usually as an afterthought) an output block that was generated a few prompts ago. Questions:

Does anyone know if this functionality already exists? I couldn't find anything that was ready-made.

Wrote the following to do the job, and would greatly appreciate any feedback about whether I've missed potentially dangerous cases.


(defun mm-comint-delete-this-output ()
  "Assuming point is in comint output, search backwards and forwards for
  the next comint prompt, select the region in between them (this
  presumably corresponds to the entire output in which point is located),
  and kill it."
  (interactive)
  (save-excursion
    (search-backward-regexp comint-prompt-regexp)
    (forward-line)
    (setq begin (point)) ; (insert "<<START>>")
    (search-forward-regexp comint-prompt-regexp)
    (forward-line -1)
    (setq end (point)) ; (insert "<<END>>")))
    (comint-kill-region begin end)
    (insert "\n")))

Thanks!

I don't know that there is much danger here. Even if you miss some or delete more than you want, it's not the end of the world: you could delete more by hand in the first case, or you could always get it back by undoing the deletion or by re-executing a previous command from the history in the second.
That said, regexp matching is always subject to failures because of coincidental spurious matches: something matching your prompt in the text will foul up things.
You might be better off using the field properties of comint output - see Defining and Using Fields in the Emacs Lisp Ref manual. If you are at a point inside the text that you want to delete, you can say:
M-: (delete-field)

If you know a buffer position in the text that you want to delete, you can do it remotely:
M-: (delete-field <POS>)

Both of these might delete something that is not quite what you want (in particular, prompts are considered output and they are deleted). But, depending on your needs, it might just be the ticket - and it is certainly simpler.
